# Provide class name dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a class as below where permission id's of the pages are defined. Passing the permission id's I get the permissions from the database.

```
public class PermissionIdConstants
{
  public class SubMenus
  {
    public class MySubMenu1{
      public const int TRAINING = 26;
      public const int USER_INFO = 3;
    }

    public class MySubMenu2{
      public const int TASKS = 2;
      public const int USER_INFO = 5;   
    }  
  }
}
```

Now based on which submenu is clicked I have to pass the permission id's to  a method as below

When SubMenu2 User_Info is clicked

```
getPermissions(PermissionIdConstants.SubMenus.MySubMenu2);
```

When SubMenu1 User_Info is clicked

```
getPermissions(PermissionIdConstants.SubMenus.MySubMenu1);
```

Now I wanted to know if the submneu can be passed dynamically. Somethig similar to

```
getPermissions(PermissionIdConstants.SubMenus. + mysubmenu );
```

If it was enum i could have used Enum.parse. But i am not so sure if this can be done here.

Comment: Honestly, I think you have a design issue more than anything else.  Those task identifiers *should* be together in a single enum, or at least grouped together as static members in the same class.  It appears you are forcing constants to group together with interface structure, which is asking for trouble and causing issues.

Comment: Sadly that is how it was designed long ago. Changing everything is a huge amount of rework. aspx pages and mvc pages co exists in the application. I am trying to make a generic method for mvc pages.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you should use an `enum` for such a case, I'll try to give you a solution for current issue.

Assuming that your `getPermissions` function have something like this as its current signature:

```
bool getPermissions(Type menu)
```

You can change it to something like this and use the [Type.GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/vstudio/w3f99sx1.aspx) function:

```
bool getPermissions(string menuStr)
{
    Type menu = Type.GetType(menuStr);
    ...
}
```

Then you use it like:

```
getPermissions("PermissionIdConstants.SubMenus." + mysubmenu);
```

Comment: Assuming that the classes `PermissionIdConstants.SubMenus.*` are in the executing assembly

Comment: They are not in the saem Assembly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
getPermissions(Type.GetType("PermissionIdConstants.SubMenus." + mysubmenu ));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be accessing them like that, perhaps you should be *storing* them like that:

```
public static class PermissionIdConstants
{
  public static class SubMenus
  {
    public static Dictionary<string,int> MySubMenu1 = new Dictionary<string,int>()
    {
        {"TRAINING",26},
        {"USER_INFO",1},
    };
    public static Dictionary<string,int> MySubMenu2 = new Dictionary<string,int>()
    {
        {"TASKS",2},
        {"USER_INFO",5},
    };
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
getPermissions(PermissionIdConstants.SubMenus[mysubmenu])
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to implement what you're describing.

Using an Interface, you can implement this on all your submenu classes. You'll then be refer to them by their interface. E.g.:

```
public interface ISubMenu {
    //Everything you put in here (methods, properties, ...) means that you
    //a. can still use it when your submenu is cast as an object of ISubMenu type
    //b. MUST implement these features on the classes that have your interface implemented.

    //e.g:

    public string GetMenuId(); 
}

public class SubMenus
{
    public class MySubMenu1 : ISubMenu {
      public const int TRAINING = 26;
      public const int USER_INFO = 3;

      public string GetMenuId()
      {
        return "1";
      }
    }

    public class MySubMenu2 : ISubMenu {
      public const int TASKS = 2;
      public const int USER_INFO = 5;  

      public string GetMenuId()
      {
        return "2";
      } 
    }  
}
```

Now you can call method by using the interface name as a type:

```
public string GetPermissions(ISubMenu submenu)
{
    var menu_id = submenu.GetMenuId(); 
    //this is the only function you can call at the moment
    //since this is the only one we defined in the interface.
}

//Somewhere else in the code:
var permissions = GetPermissions( new SubMenu1() );
```

You could also use [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), but I think they're not really what you're looking for in this case.

**Edit**

I just noticed you're also trying to pass your classes without creating a new instance. If this is what you want, you should make them either [static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or into a [singleton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx).

This might be beyond the scope of the question at hand, though.